# Prevent VMWare Workstation from changing display on multiple monitors (with Win10 host)

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware-workstation

I have three VMs.  All are set up to use all 4 monitors in a multi-monitor display, and they all work fine.

Overnight, however, **something happens which causes VMWare to change the multi-monitor display to use a single monitor.**
Strangely it shows as though it is using the left-most monitor in my multi-monitor setup, but it is actually displaying over the middle two monitors.  Basically, it's just messed up and unusable.

I fix it by going to non-full screen and repeat the process for going back into full screen and selecting the desired 4 monitor setup for each VM.  This solution is undesirable. :-(

I think this might be a bug but figured I'd ask to see if anyone else has seen this behavior and has a suggestion on how to fix it or troubleshoot it.

Some additional information:

- My host is Windows 10 x64 Pro.
- All 3 VMs are set to never turn off screen and never go to sleep
- The host VM is set to have screen go to sleep after 45 mins and never go to sleep.
- AFAIK, the host has not gone to sleep during this period but I don't know how to verify this.   The host in the morning is running and all VMs are running and in the *messed up configuration*.
- I've never seen this behavior before and have used VMware for many years (8+) (since Jan 2011, VMWare Workstation 7).
- All 3 VMs are set to View | Autosize | Autofit Guest being selected with "Autofit window" greyed out because the VMs are in full screen mode.
- I have a UPS connected to the host but the history of events shows no events have occured.

Searching for a solution is difficult because I have no idea what event is causing VMWare to make the change.

Some articles that I found that did not help are listed.  I searched for **vmware workstation changes multimonitor configuration**.

- [an issue with VMWare Workstation 10 and three monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/763693/an-issue-with-vmware-workstation-10-and-three-monitors)
- https://communities.vmware.com/thread/493022

Comment: I typically minimize all my VMs before locking the host.  I noticed when I left one VM open and locked that the VM did not change size like I had seen in the question I've posted.  But I haven't had time to test this methodically (yet).

Comment: I decided to let all the VMs sleep after 3 hours of inactivity, so I set them up to go to sleep after 3 hours, and set the HOST to got to sleep after 4 hours.  When I checked in the morning the same configuration was observed.  The VMs were centered across two monitors, each one needing to be woken from its sleep.